# How to get mongoose post hook fired from another js file/function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I have this location.model.js,

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var LocationsSchema = new Schema({
 name: String,
 description: String,
 country_id:{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Countries'
 },
 geo_location:{
    type: [Number] 
 },
 icon: String,
 image: String,
 status: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
 },
 created_at : {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date()
 },
 updated_at: {
    type: Date
 }
});
LocationsSchema.index({ geo_location: "2dsphere" });
module.exports = mongoose.model('Locations', LocationsSchema);
```

I do queries like find, save, update from controller file.
I'm having a location.socket file like this.

```
'use strict';
var locations = require('./locations.model');

exports.register = function(socket) {
  //socket.emit('locations:save', 'Helloooo');
  locations.schema.post('save', function (doc) {
    console.log('new location added');
  });
}
```

The mongoose post save hook is working fine, if I place that hook in model itseld. But the same hook is not getting fired when I place in location.socket.js file.
So all I need is to do socket.emit from this location.socket.js file

Edit1:
This is app.js (server startup file)

```
    var server = require('http').createServer(app);
    var socketio = require('socket.io')(server, {
      serveClient: config.env !== 'production',
      path: '/socket.io'
    });
    require('./config/socketio')(socketio);
    require('./config/express')(app);
    require('./routes')(app);

    server.listen(config.port, config.ip, function () {
          console.log('server started');
    });
```

and here is socketio config file,

```
module.exports = function (socketio) {
  socketio.on('connection', function (socket) {
    require('../api/locations/locations.socket').register(socket);
  })
}
```

Comment: I think you have to define all the mongoose hooks before you initialize your mongoose model. But thats not the case here.

Comment: All the articles I referred were saying the same point to define all mongoose hooks before mongoose model. That's what I did here too, but not getting solution.

Comment: Where are you calling this register function?

Comment: on server startup, Im sending connected client socket to this register function.

Comment: Please show the code where you are calling this function

Comment: Please edit in your question above within code block. This is hard to understand

Comment: @cEeNiKc, Updated question, please check once

Comment: See you are calling the register function on a new socket connection. But till then the app has already started and mongoose models are already initialized.

Comment: Can you please suggest a solution for this. @cEeNiKc
I have no idea to get out if this

Comment: Yeah please check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:-

```
module.exports = function (socketio) {
  require('../api/locations/locations.socket').register(socketio)
}

exports.register = function(socketio) {
  socketio.emit('locations:save', 'Helloooo');
}
```

But this will emit to every connected socket. So if you need to emit to a particular socket you need to use rooms in socketio.

Comment: Actually the issue is that mongoose post save hook is not getting fired from another js file

Comment: Yes I know that. Did you try this solution?

Comment: Yes.. this is working as usual. socketio emit is fine.